# Loading additional spring profiles from java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there any possibility to load aditional spring profiles from java config?

I know that I can use `-Dspring.profile.active` argument and also add profiles to `spring.profiles.include` in application.properties.

What I need is to be able to activate profiles from java config. I've created PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, where I'm adding some custom property files, which also contains property `spring.profiles.include`, all properties are load and it works ok, but spring doesn't activate any profiles which are inclded using this property.

```
@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc() throws IOException {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    ppc.setLocations(new ClassPathResource("properties/" + property + ".properties"));
    ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return ppc;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The active spring profiles are defined in properties via the following configuration: `spring.profiles.active:`.

You should list in all the files that you import the profiles that they activate via the above configuration key.

**EDIT**

First, as per the [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles) the configuration `spring.profiles.include` is more suitable for unconditionally adding active profiles.

Second, I can assume that `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is not suitable for what you want to achieve. The official documentation lists the ways you can [Externalize Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config). You can try to use `@PropertySource`:

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:other.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
public class Application {
       ...
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can try to list the other properties files in property `spring.config.location` inside `application.properties` as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

Comment: I tried with both `spring.profiles.active` and `spring.profiles.include`. WIth include it's work ok when it's in default application.properties or profile specific property file which spring loades by itself, however if I'm loading this with PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, it sees this property but it doesn't activate any profiles from it.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Using `spring.profiles.include` suits your needs better than overriding `spring.profiles.active`. I think the problem is that adding a new bean of type `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is not the correct approach. I will edit my answer.